# VueJS 2 to VueJS 3 migration error: (deprecation GLOBAL_MOUNT)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am seeing the error:

```
    [Vue warn]: (deprecation GLOBAL_MOUNT) The global app bootstrapping API has changed: vm.$mount() and the "el" option have been removed. Use createApp(RootComponent).mount() instead.
  Details: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#mounting-app-instance
```

I followed the documentation but the error didn't go away.

**main.js**

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import Vue, { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import moment from 'moment';

const AppComponent = defineComponent({
  components: { App },
  setup () {
    moment.locale('en');
  },
});

createApp(AppComponent)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");
```

Comment: I mean it's clearly telling you to remove the parameter to `mount()`, what exactly did you follow?

Comment: The official documentation says to keep using `app.mount('#app')`. https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#mounting-app-instance

Comment: the `createApp` part is all correct, but what is there a reason you're using `defineComponent`?  It's for typescript, and is a bit strange to be using an almost empty wrapper component (with no template) around App.vue.  Regardless, posting your `package.json` might shed more light on the error.

Comment: Did you search to see if you are creating another app instance?